# reactive feign client global retry

Tags: java, feign, openfeign, reactive-feign-client

I am switching from feign client to reactive feign client, I have defined global retryer for feign:

```
  @Bean
  Retryer retryer() {
    return new Retryer.Default(100, 1, 5);
  }

  @Bean
  ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
    return new HttpErrorDecoder();
  }

  static class HttpErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
      Exception exception = defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);

      if (response.status() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        return new RetryableException(response.status(),
            "api call for url: " + response.request().url() + " failed",
            response.request().httpMethod(), exception.getCause(), null,
            response.request());
      }

      return exception;
    }
  }
```

With non-reactive client retries works fine, with reactive client error decoder raises RetryableException as it should, but Retryer doesn't react - no retry is executed. I am using mostly webflux `Mono<T>`, is there a way how to make it work or Retryer won't work for reactive feign? If so, is it possible to define "global retries" or do I need to define retry for every call/mono ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retryer was [removed](https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive/commit/bc390a7f758ae993f017d60bb24d9650f9f41ac4) from Reactive client. You should use [ReactiveRetryPolicy](https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive/blob/master/feign-reactor-core/src/main/java/reactivefeign/retry/ReactiveRetryPolicy.java)

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRetryPolicy reactiveRetryPolicy() {
    return BasicReactiveRetryPolicy.retryWithBackoff(5, 100);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this seems to be working - it would be better if this kind of change/example appeared somewhere in documentation in the future (I wasn`t able to find it anywhere)